# Failed to install gems via Bundler (pushing to Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

i'm having a problem while pushing my Rails 4 project to GIT:

```
johann@johann-R430-P430-R480:~/projects/spread$ git push heroku master
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 133, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (90/90), done.
Writing objects: 100% (101/101), 266.75 KiB | 175 KiB/s, done.
Total 101 (delta 25), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find tomz-libsvm-ruby-swig-0.3.3 in any of the sources
       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find tomz-libsvm-ruby-swig-0.3.3 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

The app works perfectly localhost, including the tomz-libsvm-ruby-swig-0.3.3
What could be wrong? :[
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Gemfile to add an alternative source...

So instead of...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

you should have...

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'
```

And Heroku should then be able to find the gem.

Comment: I'm surprised... I took that advice from the gem's site... https://github.com/purchease/libsvm-ruby-swig  ...it clearly states that you need to add http://gems.github.com as a source. Are you (in the log) seeing gem metadata being pulled from both gem sites?

Comment: `gem 'tomz-libsvm-ruby-swig', '0.3.3', :git => 'https://github.com/purchease/libsvm-ruby-swig.git'`  that may work?

Comment: You are correct, i just forgot do re-add the modified Gemfile in the commit. Thanks you!

Comment: That's great!  :)  If you're happy with my answer, please accept it. :)